# project that uses Swift 1.1 but I only have Xcode 6.3 - what is a good sol'n

Tags: ios, xcode

So a developer delivered a project that uses Swift 1.1 but I only have Xcode 6.3. There doesn't seem to be any compiler flag to force Swift 1.1 and I really don't want to reinstall an older version. This probably shouldn't be possible or would it? Would shared libraries get messed up if I did this?

What are possible solutions? I have asked the dev to upgrade it to 1.2 but we really need to verify that functionality currently works so would rather build this current version.

Comment: You have outlined all possible solutions. Either get a copy of Xcode that includes Swift 1.1 or upgrade the project to 1.2.

Comment: would you avoid downloading an older version of Xcode to have two different versions - would OS handle different libraries correctly? Sounds like a mess. I'm just project managing this project so not super familiar with OS internals. Edit - just tried downloading Xcode and looks like swift compiler it picks up is 1.2

Comment: no worries , you can have multiple versions of Xcode installed, no mess at all.  I would suggest to convert 1.2, sooner or later you will have to do that anyway. There are multiple related questions here on SO with good hints around the topic... one is from me :)